# extracting and inserting data from JSON in Oracle

Tags: java, json, oracle

I have one JSON file and I´m trying to insert in database.

Inserts are not working, not sure if I am looping correctly json

I´ve done a very easy example:

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  remote_claimid VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

and the procedure:

```
    PROCEDURE TEST (
        p_json CLOB
    ) AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TEST (
            remote_claimid
        )
        SELECT
            remote_claimid
        FROM JSON_TABLE(
                 p_json,
                 '$.claim[*]'
                 COLUMNS(
                   remote_claimid VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.remote_claimid'
                 )
        );
               
        COMMIT;
        exception when others then 
            log_api.fatal(log_ctx, 'ERROR INSERT_TEST');
            raise;
    END TEST;
```

And this is the JSON

```
{claim=[{remote_claimid=5680}, {remote_claimid=7654}]}
```

This is the call:

```
            json = '{"claim"=[{"remote_claimid"="5680"}, {"remote_claimid"="7654"}]}'
            try {
                sql.call('{call BILLING_API.TEST(?)}', [json])
                output = [SUCCESS: true, msg: "inserts added."]
                sql.commit()
            } catch(SQLException se) {
                sql.rollback()
                log.error("Exception: ${se}; Procedure: BILLING_API.TEST; Params: Clob ${responseList}")
                output = commonDBService.processException(se)
            } finally {
                sql.close()
            }
```

Nothing is inserted, no errors... nothing
Any idea what´s happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **correct** JSON your path works:

```
SELECT
    remote_claimid
        FROM JSON_TABLE(
                 q'~{"claim" : [{"remote_claimid": 5680}, {"remote_claimid" : 7654}]}~',
                 '$.claim[*]'
                 COLUMNS(
                   remote_claimid VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.remote_claimid'
                 )
        );


5680
7654
```

Comment: Yes... but then... how must I pass the JSON to the function?

maybe the problem is there?

Comment: You should check that the remote_claimid column contains valid JSON: '"claim"=...' is not, '"claim":...' is.

Comment: Great!!
That was the reaseon!!!

I changed this:
responseList = '{"claim"=[{"remote_claimid"="52680"}, {"remote_claimid"="76354"}]}'

for this:

responseList = '{"claim":[{"remote_claimid":"52680"}, {"remote_claimid":"76354"}]}'


Now it works

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any issue in your code. But i will suggest , Can you try like this. I think this is the better way to insert json into the oracle db.

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class YourClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"claim\":[{\"remote_claimid\":\"5680\"}, {\"remote_claimid\":\"7654\"}]}";
        
        try (Connection connection = YourDatabaseConnectionProvider.getConnection()) {
            // Assuming YourDatabaseConnectionProvider is a class providing a connection to your Oracle database
            try (CallableStatement callStmt = connection.prepareCall("{call BILLING_API.TEST(?)}")) {
                callStmt.setString(1, json);
                callStmt.execute();

                // If you need to retrieve output parameters, you can do so here
                connection.commit();

                System.out.println("Inserts added.");
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                // Rollback the transaction in case of an exception
                connection.rollback();
                log.error("Exception: " + se + "; Procedure: BILLING_API.TEST; Params: Clob " + json);
                // Handle the exception or delegate it to a method like commonDBService.processException(se)
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Handle connection-related exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this code helps you.